# Conditional check in rabl

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rabl

I have question model with has many relationship of question_options.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base

  #relationship
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :question_options, :dependent => :destroy,:conditions => "is_deactivated is FALSE"
```

Question option

```
class QuestionOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :question_id,:option,:order,:is_other,:is_deactivated
  belongs_to :question
```

In my question_detail rabl I have

```
object @question
attributes :id, :status
child :question_options do
 attributes :question_id,:option,:order,:is_other
end
```

Here I want to respond only the question_option which has is_other = false

```
like the below....
    object @question
    attributes :id, :status
    child :question_options do
     attributes :question_id,:option,:order,:is_other = true
    end
```

How do I check a condition in rable that?

Comment: Are you trying to limit the rendering of Questions or QuestionOptions?

Comment: yes @phillbaker i want to limit questionoption with an condition. i need to fetch question option which has true in is_other field

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do this is to use if [`if` option on `attributes`](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/#attributes), for example:

```
object @question
attributes :id, :status
child :question_options do
 attributes :question_id,:option,:order,:is_other, 
    :if => lambda { |question_option| question_option.is_other }
end
```

Also check out the [section on conditions](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/#conditions).